# How to change the font in Squib

Tags: ruby, squib

I want to change the font in Squib.
How do I do this.

There is a font folder and also I can see where I set the font in the layout, do I need to set it anywhere else.

I'm wanting to use FiraSans-Regular.otf and FiraSans-Heavy.otf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, Squib doesn't support loading fonts locally. You'll have to install the font on your system, and then do something like `text font: 'FiraSans'`. I generally keep my font files in my git repo just for portability.

Loading local fonts has been discussed by the Pango team (what Squib uses for text), and they are making the process less painful as I understand it. http://mces.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-custom-application-fonts.html. It will be a while until that translates to Ruby, as well, since cross-platform compatibility is hard when it comes to fonts.

I've created a GitHub issue to track on this if you want to follow it:

https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/issues/105

Comment: So just to clarify I should 1. Download the font and install it as a system font (done) 2. Where do I put the 'text font: Fira Sans'? In the layout I had copied from your example on the homepage and have 'font: FiraSans Regular, sans 72' in my layout.yml under 'Title:' and similar sections. Is this right, because it's not working. Can you outline exactly what code I need where, using your example code from the squib homepage as the starting point. Thx

Comment: require 'squib'

Squib::Deck.new(cards: 2) do
  background color: 'white'
  text str: %w(Hello World!), font: 'Serif Bold 42'
  save_png prefix: 'basic_'
end

Comment: Sorry - that last comment didn't format the way I meant it:. Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/andymeneely/69b8d34c6b2951f9154f

Comment: Great!! Glad you got it.

Comment: I managed to get it working by moving my font call into deck.rb as you suggest. I also just deleted my font settings in layout.yml so there was no potential for conflict. Does this mean that specifying fonts in layout.yml does not work?

Comment: You are absolutely right - sorry about that, that's a bug. I would have totally caught it if I had been actually working on my games then Squib because that's how I usually do it. Fortunately, that behavior is gone in v0.7, which I'm releasing soon.